# AS3 - Free memory (Loader, BitmapData)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

For some reason my app is using more and more memory as it runs, and I can't figure out how to dump old data I dont need anymore.

I use a Loader to load a .png
I then use a BitmapData to store the image, so that I can go over and check each pixel and store the result.

Then I loop this x times.

When I start on the second run I don't need the old information anymore, but it looks like my app is still storing the data (the images loaded)..

Here's some of my code:

```
        public function loadImage():void{
            myLoader = new Loader();
            myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);

            if (currentFrame.toString(10).length == 1){
                currentFrameURL = txtFolder.text + "\\" + txtImageName.text + txtImageNum.text.substr(0, txtImageNum.text.length - 1) + currentFrame + txtImageType.text;
            }
            if (currentFrame.toString(10).length == 2){
                currentFrameURL = txtFolder.text + "\\" + txtImageName.text + txtImageNum.text.substr(0, txtImageNum.text.length - 2) + currentFrame + txtImageType.text;
            }
            if (currentFrame.toString(10).length == 3){
                currentFrameURL = txtFolder.text + "\\" + txtImageName.text + txtImageNum.text.substr(0, txtImageNum.text.length - 3) + currentFrame + txtImageType.text;
            }
            trace(currentFrameURL + " sent to loader...");

            myLoader.load(new URLRequest(currentFrameURL));
        }

        public function imageLoaded(event:Event):void{
            myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);

            myBitmapData = new BitmapData(parseInt(txtWidth.text),parseInt(txtHeight.text),false);
            myBitmapData.draw(event.currentTarget.content);


            //Generate preview of current image being processed..
            //myPreviewImage.source = myBitmapData;
            labelProgress.text = "Current process: " + (currentFrame + 1) + "/" + (parseInt(txtFrames.text));


            for(var y:int=0; y < parseInt(txtHeight.text) ; y++){
                for(var x:int=0; x < parseInt(txtWidth.text) ; x++){
                    currentPixelColor = myBitmapData.getPixel(x,y);
                    myTabelClass.recordPixel(currentPixelColor);
                }
            }//ett bilde ferdig scannet og lagret

            currentFrame++;

            if(currentFrame < parseInt(txtFrames.text)){
                myTabelClass.newImg(currentFrame);
                trace("sending newImg command: " + currentFrame);
                loadImage();
            }else{
                //All frames done..
                //myTabelClass.traceResult();
                Alert.show("All images scanned!\n\nClick 'OK' to add new data to XML.", "Images scanned", Alert.OK, this, insertDataToXML);
                btnSave.enabled = true;
                btnTest1.enabled = true;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is a bug preventing Loader from ever freeing memory, see here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3071138 . As per my tests, it may be related to how fast do you want to dispose the previously loaded content, but this is a *guess*, don't take it for granted.

Other things: calling `BitmapData.dispose()` frees memory "immediately", but if you don't, then BitmapData instances are still GC'ed, however, that may take longer, and the loitering bitmaps may create an impression of a memory leak.

`System.gc()` is only available in debugger, which means that your end users will not be able to use it.

Setting variables, especially local variables to null, after the object is no longer used makes no sense, if the compiler was only a little smarter, it would probably identify it as a dead code and remove altogether. Setting data members to null is only useful if you actually want them to be null for whatever reason, which is as they call it, "a business logic reason", don't try to "help" the GC, all chances are you will do more harm then good. When I come across a code that assigns `null`, this usually lights a red bulb, it is rather a bad design, or redundancy. If your code is good, you shouldn't need to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your helpfull inputs! =) 
I see that my app GC properly if I use smaller images (less data), but my overnight experiment failed as it reached frame 97 of the full-frame example. I'll look more into it.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to multithread?
I've got 2x Xeon processors, which gives me 16 threads. My app only uses 1 thread at 100%.. It's not critical, but it would speed up my app by a factor of 16 if it was possible..

Comment: Are you giving it time to dispose?  GC calls take time, they are not immediate.  Use the profiler.  Loader/BitmapData dispose fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Once you're done with `myBitmapData`, call `myBitmapData.dispose()` and `myBitmapData = null`. Keep in mind that after you call `dispose()`, your `BitmapData` object is not usable anymore, so you have to create a new instance (`myBitmapData = new BitmapData()`).

By the way, I did not analyze you code much, but I've noticed that you copied each image's bitmapData with `draw()` and then worked on it. You could work directly with loaded images content, that would save memory as well:

`myBitmapData = Bitmap(event.target.content).bitmapData;`

and don't forget to `null` each image before proceeding to the next frame if you do not intend to use them later.

Comment: I tried adding myBitmapData.dispose(); to the end, but this throws an error the next time I load in an image..

Answer (score 0):

You're in recursion, so yes, you don't release the preview image loaded.

Try to set `myBitmapData = null` before call `loadImage()` again.

If nothing happen you can try force a garbage collector by calling `System.gc()` before loadImage:

```
myBitmapData = null;
System.gc();
loadImage();
```

But thats not a good practice they say. :P

If nothing works just remove the recursion thing that may help.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out now.
What do you mean by remove recursion?

Comment: `loadImage` calls `imageLoaded` and `imageLoaded` calls `loadImage` again. You may need to remake your logic without using this recursion.

Comment: ahh, I'll look into it :) Thanks for pointing it out ;)
Though, not 100% sure how I'd do this without recursion.

Comment: nulling out the bitmapdata worked in a way.
first 2 images loaded without increse of memory useage, but then it started to increase.. Gotta look into that recursion problem.. Got any ideas how to fix this? =)

Comment: Try out the `.dispose()` as our buddy said. I forgot that =p

Comment: Still goed up to 140 000 k from 79 000 k (before it was 180 from 79) over 5 frames. It should't eat up this much memory?

Last run I tried 100 frames, and I was using close to 2 000 000 k

Comment: is that memory a big problem? if don't, the GC may do the job in the right time for you. Also try to remove the recursion. Make something like `for eachFrame : doWatINeed()`. Just as a test change your `loadImage()` by `setInterval(loadImage, 1000)` this will call loadImage after 1s. Let's see your memory behavior.

Comment: It's not a big problem if the GC comes in and does it's jub before memory is full. But my machine's got 12Gb of memory, so should not be a problem. I just thought it would be nice to figure it out if it was a problem :)

I'll try the setInterval you mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have covered how to deal with `BitmapData` but I've noticed that `Loader`s seem to hold on to memory as well. Unfortunately I cannot point to any specific sources other than my experience. You can give this a try to see what shakes out:

Move the line

```
myLoader = new Loader();
```

out of the `loadImage()` function and instantiate that variable in the class constructor. This will allow you to reuse the same `Loader` instance over and over again.